# I want to scroll bar in bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table, it has a `min-width`. When it has a few context, the scroll bar is in the page centre. I want scroll bar at the bottom. But this doesn't work:

```html
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" style="position: relative;overflow:auto;height:100%">
    <div class="row clearfix">
      <div class="col-xs-3" id="pollutanttree"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-9">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
            add
          </button>

        </div>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="min-width:1200px">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>
                name
              </th>

            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>

          </tbody>

        </table>

      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix" style="position: absolute;bottom:0px">this should in bottom ,on the scroll bar</div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this by adding this code:

```
body{
   height:100vh;
}
```

and that means that you are giving the body the full screen height

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code

```
body, html, .container-fluid{
height:100%;
}
```